# CodeIgniter MySQL query not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to get this query to work in CodeIgniter but it's spitting out an error:

> A Database Error Occurred Error
>   Number: 1096
>
> No tables used
>
> SELECT *

If I put the query directly into MySQL it works fine (I replace the $variables with values).  Here is the query as input into codeigniter:

```
$this->db->query(" 
    SELECT * 
    FROM writing_quests 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN members_quests_completed 
    ON members_quests_completed.quest_id = writing_quests.id 
    WHERE writing_quests.level_required <=  $userlevel 
    AND ( 
        members_quests_completed.user_id = $user_id
        OR 
        members_quests_completed.user_id IS NULL )"
);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Am I doing something that is wrong and I am missing it?
I've included the whole function call in case the problem is somewhere else?  I've done this exact thing many times without an issue.

```
function get_all_quests_for_user() {
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $userlevel = $this->session->userdata('user_level');

    $this->db->query("SELECT writing_quests.id, writing_quests.points_availible, writing_quests.name, writing_quests.note, writing_quests.instructions, writing_quests.time_limit, members_quests_completed.location_completed, members_quests_completed.status  FROM writing_quests LEFT OUTER JOIN members_quests_completed ON members_quests_completed.quest_id = writing_quests.id WHERE writing_quests.level_required <=  '$userlevel' AND writing_quests.unlocked = 1 AND ( members_quests_completed.user_id = '$user_id' OR members_quests_completed.user_id IS NULL )");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $this->db->last_query();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps CI's `query()` method doesn't like line breaks.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock.  I've atcually tried it without.  I also have queries written with line breaks that do work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT writing_quests.*, ( put needed fields from members_quests_completed ) 
FROM writing_quests
LEFT JOIN members_quests_completed ....
```

same fields names corrupting results column's names in result object

FYI it not wise to use *, you should have list of fields...
and what is most important:

```
$result = $this->db->query ( ... );
```

$this->db->query ( ... ) is good when INSERT or UPDATE (mostly), when you pulling data assign results to variable: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Comment: Added a field list, same result, same error.  This works fine in mysql  command line.

Comment: yes, it does work fine in mysql.  This is why I'm so confused.

Comment: second part of answer handle CI part

Answer (score 6):

I think it should be like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query(" 
SELECT * 
FROM writing_quests 
LEFT OUTER JOIN members_quests_completed 
ON members_quests_completed.quest_id = writing_quests.id 
WHERE writing_quests.level_required <=  $userlevel 
AND ( 
    members_quests_completed.user_id = $user_id
    OR 
    members_quests_completed.user_id IS NULL )"
);
```

Or:

```
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
```